# How can you properly automatically set which interactive report you navigate to in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using oracle apex 4.2 and was wondering if there is a special way to link to a certain default report that I created. So for example below I have made Region Name Pie report along with the default. I changed the aliases to 1 and 2 respectively. I tried using the link example but the synatx is malformed, so I tried another option below.
[image]

Here, I tried to set the Report ID Item to a variable that I set as I move to this page. And I looked at the session and this value is being set to 1 as needed(I assumed it was the Report alias I needed to set the value to).
[image]

Are these methods viable in Oracle or am I doing anything that is noticeably wrong? Thanks.

Edit: Error for Syntax:
[image]

Comment: how and where are the url's been submited? What's the browser showing you when the url is requested? Post a complete url from you browser

Comment: If you want to access a default report on every page.You should make a report on a global page, assuming I understand what your trying to say though.

Comment: @brenners1302 It's not that I want to access a default report on every page, I want to be able to go to the page the report is located on and instead of going to the primary default report(which always happens) I want to go to the alternate default report first. And the PARAM2 variable is a global variable if that helps. Does that clear things up a bit? Thanks.

Comment: @Typo I am going straight to this page from a login page, add the url is standard (f?p=138:5:), but I set the global variable PARAM2 before I branch to the page with this interactive report. I also tried using the url provided which is (f?p=138:5:&APP_SESSION.:IR_REPORT1) which does not work because I get a malformed syntax error. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The link examples there should work. What is the "syntax error" you are getting?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I added the error and url to the post.

Comment: The `&APP_SESSION.` substitution variable hasn't been replaced - which means you're copying-and-pasting the URL in a place which doesn't do the replacement. Where are you putting the URL? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: Thank you, @JeffreyKemp. That solved the malformed syntax error. The replacement wasn't occurring with the APP_SESSION, I am able to get to the report with the URL now, I will play around with it now!